# Matlab / Octave problem with code of 3rd person

Tags: matlab, octave

I am using the following matlab code in octave to generate a numerical derivative from noisy data.
I am new to matlab/octave and I absolutly don't know how to handle it.

```
function u = TVRegDiff(data, iter, alph, u0, scale, ep, dx, plotflag, diagflag)
% u = TVRegDiff(data, iter, alph, u0, scale, ep, dx, plotflag, diagflag);
% u = tvdiff(e, dx, iter, ep, alph);
% Rick Chartrand(rickc@lanl.gov), Apr. 10, 2011
% Please cite Rick Chartrand, "Numerical differentiation of noisy,
% nonsmooth data, " ISRN Applied Mathematics, Vol. 2011, Article ID 164564, 
% 2011.
%
% Inputs:  (First three required; omitting the final N parameters for N < 7
    % or passing in[] results in default values being used.)
    % data        Vector of data to be differentiated.
    %
    %       iter        Number of iterations to run the main loop.A stopping
    %                   condition based on the norm of the gradient vector g
    %                   below would be an easy modification.No default value.
    %
    %       alph        Regularization parameter.This is the main parameter
    %                   to fiddle with.Start by varying by orders of
    %                   magnitude until reasonable results are obtained.A
    %                   value to the nearest power of 10 is usally adequate.
    %                   No default value.Higher values increase
    %                   regularization strenght and improve conditioning.
    %
    %       u0          Initialization of the iteration.Default value is the
    %                   naive derivative(without scaling), of appropriate
    %                   length(this being different for the two methods).
    %                   Although the solution is theoretically independent of
    %                   the intialization, a poor choice can exacerbate
    %                   conditioning issues when the linear system is solved.
    %
    %       scale       'large' or 'small' (case insensitive).Default is
    %                   'small'.  'small' has somewhat better boundary
    %                   behavior, but becomes unwieldly for data larger than
    % 1000 entries or so.  'large' has simpler numerics but
    %                   is more efficient for large - scale problems.  'large' is
    %                   more readily modified for higher - order derivatives,
    %                   since the implicit differentiation matrix is square.
    %
    %       ep          Parameter for avoiding division by zero.Default value
    %                   is 1e-6.Results should not be very sensitive to the
    %                   value.Larger values improve conditioning and
    %                   therefore speed, while smaller values give more
    %                   accurate results with sharper jumps.
    %
    %       dx          Grid spacing, used in the definition of the derivative
    %                   operators.Default is the reciprocal of the data size.
    %
    %       plotflag    Flag whether to display plot at each iteration.
    %                   Default is 1 (yes).Useful, but adds significant
    %                   running time.
    %
    %       diagflag    Flag whether to display diagnostics at each
    %                   iteration.Default is 1 (yes).Useful for diagnosing
    %                   preconditioning problems.When tolerance is not met,
    %                   an early iterate being best is more worrying than a
    %                   large relative residual.
    %
    % Output:
%
%       u           Estimate of the regularized derivative of data.Due to
%                   different grid assumptions, length(u) =
%                   length(data) + 1 if scale = 'small', otherwise
%                   length(u) = length(data).

%% Copyright notice :
% Copyright 2010. Los Alamos National Security, LLC.This material
% was produced under U.S.Government contract DE - AC52 - 06NA25396 for
% Los Alamos National Laboratory, which is operated by Los Alamos
% National Security, LLC, for the U.S.Department of Energy.The
% Government is granted for, itself and others acting on its
% behalf, a paid - up, nonexclusive, irrevocable worldwide license in
% this material to reproduce, prepare derivative works, and perform
% publicly and display publicly.Beginning five(5) years after
% (March 31, 2011) permission to assert copyright was obtained,
% subject to additional five - year worldwide renewals, the
% Government is granted for itself and others acting on its behalf
% a paid - up, nonexclusive, irrevocable worldwide license in this
% material to reproduce, prepare derivative works, distribute
% copies to the public, perform publicly and display publicly, and
% to permit others to do so.NEITHER THE UNITED STATES NOR THE
% UNITED STATES DEPARTMENT OF ENERGY, NOR LOS ALAMOS NATIONAL
% SECURITY, LLC, NOR ANY OF THEIR EMPLOYEES, MAKES ANY WARRANTY,
% EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, OR ASSUMES ANY LEGAL LIABILITY OR
% RESPONSIBILITY FOR THE ACCURACY, COMPLETENESS, OR USEFULNESS OF
% ANY INFORMATION, APPARATUS, PRODUCT, OR PROCESS DISCLOSED, OR
% REPRESENTS THAT ITS USE WOULD NOT INFRINGE PRIVATELY OWNED
% RIGHTS.

%% BSD License notice :
% Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
% modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
% are met :
%
%      Redistributions of source code must retain the above
%      copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
%      disclaimer.
%      Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
%      copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
%      disclaimer in the documentation and / or other materials
%      provided with the distribution.
%      Neither the name of Los Alamos National Security nor the names of its
%      contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
%      derived from this software without specific prior written
%      permission.
%
% THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND
% CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES,
% INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
% MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
% DISCLAIMED.IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR
% CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
% SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES(INCLUDING, BUT NOT
    % LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF
    % USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED
    % AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
    % LIABILITY, OR TORT(INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
    % ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
    % POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

    %% code starts here
    % Make sure we have a column vector.
    data = data(:);
% Get the data size.
n = length(data);

% Default checking. (u0 is done separately within each method.)
if nargin < 9 || isempty(diagflag)
    diagflag = 1;
end
if nargin < 8 || isempty(plotflag)
    plotflag = 1;
end
if nargin < 7 || isempty(dx)
    dx = 1 / n;
end
if nargin < 6 || isempty(ep)
    ep = 1e-6;
end
if nargin < 5 || isempty(scale)
    scale = 'small';
end

% Different methods for small - and large - scale problems.
switch lower(scale)

case 'small'
% Construct differentiation matrix.
c = ones(n + 1, 1) / dx;
D = spdiags([-c, c], [0, 1], n, n + 1);
clear c
DT = D';
% Construct antidifferentiation operator and its adjoint.
A = @(x) chop(cumsum(x) - 0.5 * (x + x(1))) * dx;
AT = @(w) (sum(w) * ones(n + 1, 1) - [sum(w) / 2; cumsum(w) - w / 2]) * dx;
% Default initialization is naive derivative.
if nargin < 4 || isempty(u0)
    u0 = [0; diff(data); 0];
end
u = u0;
% Since Au(0) = 0, we need to adjust.
ofst = data(1);
% Precompute.
ATb = AT(ofst - data);

% Main loop.
for ii = 1 : iter
% Diagonal matrix of weights, for linearizing E - L equation.
Q = spdiags(1 . / (sqrt((D * u). ^ 2 + ep)), 0, n, n);
% Linearized diffusion matrix, also approximation of Hessian.
L = dx * DT * Q * D;
% Gradient of functional.
g = AT(A(u)) + ATb + alph * L * u;
% Prepare to solve linear equation.
tol = 1e-4;
maxit = 100;
% Simple preconditioner.
P = alph * spdiags(spdiags(L, 0) + 1, 0, n + 1, n + 1);
if diagflag
s = pcg(@(v) (alph * L * v + AT(A(v))), g, tol, maxit, P );
fprintf('iteration %4d: relative change = %.3e, gradient norm = %.3e\n', ii, norm(s) / norm(u), norm(g));
else
[s, ~] = pcg(@(v) (alph * L * v + AT(A(v))), g, tol, maxit, P );
end
% Update solution.
u = u - s;
% Display plot.
if plotflag
plot(u, 'ok'), drawnow;
end
end

case 'large'
% Construct antidifferentiation operator and its adjoint.
A = @(v) cumsum(v);
AT = @(w) (sum(w) * ones(length(w), 1) - [0; cumsum(w(1 : end - 1))]);
% Construct differentiation matrix.
c = ones(n, 1);
D = spdiags([-c c], [0 1], n, n) / dx;
D(n, n) = 0;
clear c
DT = D';
% Since Au(0) = 0, we need to adjust.
data = data - data(1);
% Default initialization is naive derivative.
if nargin < 4 || isempty(u0)
    u0 = [0; diff(data)];
end
u = u0;
% Precompute.
ATd = AT(data);

% Main loop.
for ii = 1 : iter
% Diagonal matrix of weights, for linearizing E - L equation.
Q = spdiags(1. / sqrt((D * u). ^ 2 + ep), 0, n, n);
% Linearized diffusion matrix, also approximation of Hessian.
L = DT * Q * D;
% Gradient of functional.
g = AT(A(u)) - ATd;
g = g + alph * L * u;
% Build preconditioner.
c = cumsum(n : -1 : 1).';
B = alph * L + spdiags(c(end : -1 : 1), 0, n, n);
droptol = 1.0e-2;
R = cholinc(B, droptol);
% Prepare to solve linear equation.
tol = 1.0e-4;
maxit = 100;
if diagflag
s = pcg(@(x) (alph * L * x + AT(A(x))), -g, tol, maxit, R', R );
fprintf('iteration %2d: relative change = %.3e, gradient norm = %.3e\n', ii, norm(s) / norm(u), norm(g));
else
[s, ~] = pcg(@(x) (alph * L * x + AT(A(x))), -g, tol, maxit, R', R );
end
% Update current solution
u = u + s;
% Display plot.
if plotflag
plot(u, 'ok'), drawnow;
end
end
end

% Utility function.
function w = chop(v)
w = v(2 : end);
```

this code was given by the autor of the paper: "Discovering governing equations from data by sparse identification of nonlinear dynamical systems"
at the line "A = @(x) chop(cumsum(x) - 0.5 * (x + x(1))) * dx;" there occurs the following error:

```
warning: called from
  chop at line 47 column 5
  TVRegDiff>@<anonymous> at line 41 column 57
  TVRegDiff at line 60 column 9
  Diff at line 140 column 3
error: Invalid call to chop.  Correct usage is:

 -- chop (X, NDIGITS, BASE)
error: called from
    print_usage at line 91 column 5
    chop at line 79 column 5
    TVRegDiff>@<anonymous> at line 41 column 57
    TVRegDiff at line 60 column 9
    Diff at line 140 column 3
>> SINDyTestSinglePendulum
```

I've read, that the @ operator is some kind of refference... but there is no variable "x" in the hole code...
Also I recognized, that the hole matlab file has no "endfunction" command.
And the last lines are also very strange.

I have no idea how to run this.

Comment: The `@` is used to create an *"anonymous function"*, go and read the documentation to understand why you the `x` doesn't refer to some variable earlier in the code. This question is currently too broad, this is a Q&A site, not a place for tutorials - you would be better to ask the author of the code if you need help understanding it!

Comment: thanks @Wolfie the information "anonymous function" helped a lot! =)

Comment: @Thomas [This reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html) may be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code you posted, `chop` is defined as a helper function at the end of the file. Such functions at the end of function m-files are called "subfunctions", and are only expected to be visible from the 'main' function defined in the file.

However, octave also provides a native `chop` function (which is supposed to be deprecated by octave v6).

It appears your code is failing to run the helper function, and attempting to run the native function instead.

Are you running this m-file as intended, or have you perhaps copy / pasted code and trying to run as a script?

**UPDATE**: There were a lot of problems with that code, mostly to do with unclear indentation obfuscating the intent of the code and introducing bugs. The 'chop' function was specified as a nested function rather than as a subfunction due to the lack of `end`points. Subfunctions are generally more reliable than nested functions in octave, if no nesting functionality is required.

I have cleaned up the code a bit, and moved the 'chop' function to a proper subfunction. Copy paste this file and replace the old one. Hopefully this will work better for you and will be easier to debug.

```matlab
function u = TVRegDiff(data, iter, alph, u0, scale, ep, dx, plotflag, diagflag)
% Usage:
%    u = TVRegDiff(data, iter, alph, u0, scale, ep, dx, plotflag, diagflag);
%    u = tvdiff(e, dx, iter, ep, alph);
%
% Rick Chartrand(rickc@lanl.gov), Apr. 10, 2011
%
% Please cite:
%    Rick Chartrand, "Numerical differentiation of noisy, nonsmooth data", ISRN Applied Mathematics, Vol. 2011,
%    Article ID 164564, 2011.
%
% Inputs:  (First three required; omitting the final N parameters for N < 7 or passing in[] results in default values
%           being used.)
%
%    data    Vector of data to be differentiated.
%
%    iter    Number of iterations to run the main loop.A stopping condition based on the norm of the gradient vector g
%            below would be an easy modification.No default value.
%
%    alph    Regularization parameter.This is the main parameter to fiddle with.Start by varying by orders of magnitude
%            until reasonable results are obtained.A value to the nearest power of 10 is usally adequate. No default
%            value.Higher values increase regularization strenght and improve conditioning.
%
%    u0      Initialization of the iteration.Default value is the naive derivative(without scaling), of appropriate
%            length(this being different for the two methods). Although the solution is theoretically independent of the
%            intialization, a poor choice can exacerbate conditioning issues when the linear system is solved.
%
%    scale   'large' or 'small' (case insensitive).Default is 'small'. 'small' has somewhat better boundary behavior, but
%            becomes unwieldly for data larger than 1000 entries or so. 'large' has simpler numerics but is more
%            efficient for large - scale problems. 'large' is more readily modified for higher - order derivatives, since
%            the implicit differentiation matrix is square.
%
%    ep      Parameter for avoiding division by zero.Default value is 1e-6.Results should not be very sensitive to the
%            value.Larger values improve conditioning and therefore speed, while smaller values give more accurate
%            results with sharper jumps.
%
%    dx      Grid spacing, used in the definition of the derivative operators.Default is the reciprocal of the data size.
%
%    plotflag   Flag whether to display plot at each iteration. Default is 1 (yes).Useful, but adds significant running
%               time.
%
%    diagflag   Flag whether to display diagnostics at each iteration.Default is 1 (yes).Useful for diagnosing
%               preconditioning problems.When tolerance is not met, an early iterate being best is more worrying than a
%               large relative residual.
%
% Output:
%
%    u    Estimate of the regularized derivative of data.Due to different grid assumptions, length(u) = length(data) + 1
%         if scale = 'small', otherwise length(u) = length(data).

%% Copyright notice :
% Copyright 2010. Los Alamos National Security, LLC.This material
% was produced under U.S.Government contract DE - AC52 - 06NA25396 for
% Los Alamos National Laboratory, which is operated by Los Alamos
% National Security, LLC, for the U.S.Department of Energy.The
% Government is granted for, itself and others acting on its
% behalf, a paid - up, nonexclusive, irrevocable worldwide license in
% this material to reproduce, prepare derivative works, and perform
% publicly and display publicly.Beginning five(5) years after
% (March 31, 2011) permission to assert copyright was obtained,
% subject to additional five - year worldwide renewals, the
% Government is granted for itself and others acting on its behalf
% a paid - up, nonexclusive, irrevocable worldwide license in this
% material to reproduce, prepare derivative works, distribute
% copies to the public, perform publicly and display publicly, and
% to permit others to do so.NEITHER THE UNITED STATES NOR THE
% UNITED STATES DEPARTMENT OF ENERGY, NOR LOS ALAMOS NATIONAL
% SECURITY, LLC, NOR ANY OF THEIR EMPLOYEES, MAKES ANY WARRANTY,
% EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, OR ASSUMES ANY LEGAL LIABILITY OR
% RESPONSIBILITY FOR THE ACCURACY, COMPLETENESS, OR USEFULNESS OF
% ANY INFORMATION, APPARATUS, PRODUCT, OR PROCESS DISCLOSED, OR
% REPRESENTS THAT ITS USE WOULD NOT INFRINGE PRIVATELY OWNED
% RIGHTS.

%% BSD License notice :
% Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
% modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
% are met :
%
%      Redistributions of source code must retain the above
%      copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
%      disclaimer.
%      Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
%      copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
%      disclaimer in the documentation and / or other materials
%      provided with the distribution.
%      Neither the name of Los Alamos National Security nor the names of its
%      contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
%      derived from this software without specific prior written
%      permission.
%
% THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND
% CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES,
% INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
% MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
% DISCLAIMED.IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR
% CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
% SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES(INCLUDING, BUT NOT
    % LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF
    % USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED
    % AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
    % LIABILITY, OR TORT(INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
    % ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
    % POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

%% code starts here

  % Make sure we have a column vector.
    data = data(:);

  % Get the data size.
    n = length(data);

  % Default checking. (u0 is done separately within each method.)
    if nargin < 9 || isempty(diagflag) , diagflag = 1    ; end
    if nargin < 8 || isempty(plotflag) , plotflag = 1    ; end
    if nargin < 7 || isempty(dx)       , dx = 1 / n      ; end
    if nargin < 6 || isempty(ep)       , ep = 1e-6       ; end
    if nargin < 5 || isempty(scale)    , scale = 'small' ; end

  % Different methods for small - and large - scale problems.
    switch lower(scale)

        case 'small'

          % Construct differentiation matrix.
            c = ones(n + 1, 1) / dx;
            D = spdiags([-c, c], [0, 1], n, n + 1);
            clear c
            DT = D';

          % Construct antidifferentiation operator and its adjoint.
            A  = @(x) chop(cumsum(x) - 0.5 * (x + x(1))) * dx;
            AT = @(w) (sum(w) * ones(n + 1, 1) - [sum(w) / 2; cumsum(w) - w / 2]) * dx;

          % Default initialization is naive derivative.
            if nargin < 4 || isempty(u0)
                u0 = [0; diff(data); 0];
            end

            u = u0;

          % Since Au(0) = 0, we need to adjust.
            ofst = data(1);

          % Precompute.
            ATb = AT(ofst - data);

          % Main loop.
            for ii = 1 : iter

              % Diagonal matrix of weights, for linearizing E - L equation.
                Q = spdiags(1 ./ (sqrt((D * u) .^ 2 + ep)), 0, n, n);

              % Linearized diffusion matrix, also approximation of Hessian.
                L = dx * DT * Q * D;

              % Gradient of functional.
                g = AT(A(u)) + ATb + alph * L * u;

              % Prepare to solve linear equation.
                tol   = 1e-4;
                maxit = 100;

              % Simple preconditioner.
                P = alph * spdiags(spdiags(L, 0) + 1, 0, n + 1, n + 1);

                if diagflag
                    s = pcg(@(v) (alph * L * v + AT(A(v))), g, tol, maxit, P );
                    fprintf('iteration %4d: relative change = %.3e, gradient norm = %.3e\n', ii, norm(s) / norm(u), norm(g));
                else
                    [s, ~] = pcg(@(v) (alph * L * v + AT(A(v))), g, tol, maxit, P );
                end

              % Update solution.
                u = u - s;

              % Display plot.
                if plotflag
                    plot(u, 'ok'), drawnow;
                end
            end   % end of for loop

      % End of case 'small' (note: cases do not require an 'end' keyword)

        case 'large'

          % Construct antidifferentiation operator and its adjoint.
            A  = @(v) cumsum(v);
            AT = @(w) (sum(w) * ones(length(w), 1) - [0; cumsum(w(1 : end - 1))]);

          % Construct differentiation matrix.
            c       = ones(n, 1);
            D       = spdiags([-c c], [0 1], n, n) / dx;
            D(n, n) = 0;

            clear c
            DT = D';

          % Since Au(0) = 0, we need to adjust.
            data = data - data(1);

          % Default initialization is naive derivative.
            if nargin < 4 || isempty(u0)
                u0 = [0; diff(data)];
            end

            u = u0;

          % Precompute.
            ATd = AT(data);

          % Main loop.
            for ii = 1 : iter

              % Diagonal matrix of weights, for linearizing E - L equation.
                Q = spdiags(1 ./ sqrt((D * u) .^ 2 + ep), 0, n, n);

              % Linearized diffusion matrix, also approximation of Hessian.
                L = DT * Q * D;

              % Gradient of functional.
                g = AT(A(u)) - ATd;
                g = g + alph * L * u;

              % Build preconditioner.
                c       = cumsum(n : -1 : 1).';
                B       = alph * L + spdiags(c(end : -1 : 1), 0, n, n);
                droptol = 1.0e-2;
                R       = cholinc(B, droptol);

              % Prepare to solve linear equation.
                tol   = 1.0e-4;
                maxit = 100;

                if diagflag
                    s = pcg(@(x) (alph * L * x + AT(A(x))), -g, tol, maxit, R', R );
                    fprintf('iteration %2d: relative change = %.3e, gradient norm = %.3e\n', ii, norm(s) / norm(u), norm(g));
                else
                    [s, ~] = pcg(@(x) (alph * L * x + AT(A(x))), -g, tol, maxit, R', R );
                end

              % Update current solution
                u = u + s;

              % Display plot.
                if plotflag
                    plot(u, 'ok'), drawnow;
                end

            end   % end of for loop

      % End of case 'large' (note: cases do not require an 'end' keyword)

    end   % end of switch block

end   % end of 'main' function



function w = chop(v)
% Utility (sub)function.
    w = v(2 : end);
end
```

Comment: Also, yes, I agree with you. The author should have included an `end` (or `endfunction` if you want to be more octave idiomatic) at the end of their subfunction for clarity and safer code. It's not just that, the whole thing has very unhelpful indentation ... I would start by indenting the code properly to help you see what's going on more clearly ...